# Mapping JSON with knockout fails to populate type defined object properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to map JSON data using the knockout.mapping plugin, however the heirarcical JSON data fails to populate my object properties correctly, the top level loads fine but not the child 'RootTarget'  data?

What am I doing wrong?

**Knockout Javascript**

```
var Query = function(json)
{
    this.ID = ko.observable(0);
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.RootTargetID = ko.observable();
    this.RootTarget = ko.observable();

    var mapping = {
        'RootTarget': {
            create: function (args) {
                return new QueryTarget(args.data, null);
            }
        }
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping, this);
}


var QueryTarget = function(json, parent)
{
    this.ID = ko.observable(0);
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.ParentID = ko.observable(0);
    this.Parent = ko.observable(parent);
    this.FilterID = ko.observable(0);

    var mapping = {
        'ignore': ["Parent"]
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping, this);
}

var QueryModuleViewModel = function()
{
    var json = {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Northwind 2",
        "RootTargetID": 2,
        "RootTarget": {
            "ID": 2,
            "Name": "Customers",
            "ParentID": null,
            "FilterID": 2,
            "Parent": null
        }
    };

    this.QueryObj = new Query(json);
}

window.onload = function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new QueryModuleViewModel());
};
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript Knockout Mapping Query Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="my_js_query_test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript Knockout Mapping Query Test</h1>
    <div data-bind="with: QueryObj">
        <span data-bind="blah: console.log($context)"></span>

        <p>Query Name: <input data-bind="value: Name" /></p>

        <hr />
        <p>Quick test of RootTarget Values</p>
        <p>RootTarget.ID: <input data-bind="value: RootTarget.ID" /></p>
        <p>RootTarget.Name: <input data-bind="value: RootTarget.Name" /></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you plz post jsfiddle example ?just copy your json data and test with it as static data

Comment: Sorry, should have done that in the frist place. Fortunatly @nevesv has posted a fiddle fix in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `RootTarget` is declared as an `ko.observable` which is a function so you need to call it with empty args `()` to get its value and access the stored object.

So you just need to change your bindings and add the missing `()`:

```
<p>RootTarget.ID: <input data-bind="value: RootTarget().ID" /></p>
<p>RootTarget.Name: <input data-bind="value: RootTarget().Name" /></p>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HD7eW/)

Or you can use here the `with` binding

```
<p>Quick test of RootTarget Values</p>
<!-- ko with: RootTarget -->
   <p>RootTarget.ID: <input data-bind="value: ID" /></p>
   <p>RootTarget.Name: <input data-bind="value: Name" /></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/B4ha3/)

It has some nice advantages:

- you don't have to repeat `RootTarget`
- the `with` automatically unwraps the observables so you can just write `with: RootTarget`, no parens needed
- it works for the case when the `RootTarget` value is `null` or `undified` so it hides the inputs while your original solution `RootTarget().ID` would throw a null reference exception.

Comment: I am such an idiot, lol, I knew it was something simple but just couldn't see the obvious, thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets on your roottarget mappings as you need to evaluate the observable before you can get it's properties.

```
<p>RootTarget.ID: <input data-bind="value: RootTarget().ID" /></p>
```

Alternatively, RootTarget doesn't actually need to be an observable, only its properties do, so if you remove the line below it'll automatically be created as a normal object and your bindings will work as they are.

```
this.RootTarget = ko.observable;
```

Comment: It was converted from a TypeScript class definition for this question, but I guess the same rules will apply there too, good tip! Thank you :)